# How can I create a shopping cart for ticket sales

Tags: php

There seems to be a problem with my code that i am unable to fix. I am getting errors that i am having trouble with.

The error is:

> Undefined index id, undefined variable result, and undefined variable i

How do I fix this?

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'connect.php';
require 'item.php';
$relult = mysqli_query($link, 'select * from tickets where id='.$_GET['id']);
$product = mysqli_fetch_object($result);
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $item= new Item();
    $item->id = $product->id;
    $item->name = $product->game;
    $item->price = $product->price;
    $item->quantity = 1; 
    $_SESSION['cart'][] = $item;
}
?>
<table align="center">
<td colspan="11"><h4> Upcoming games 2016/2017</h3> <td>
  <tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>game</th>
    <th>price</th>
    <th>stadium</th>
    <th>quantity</th>
    <th>Sub Total</th>
  </tr>       
    <?php
    $cart = unserialize(serialize($_SESSION['cart']));
    for($i-0; $i<count($cart); $i++){
    ?>
     <tr> 
         <td><?php echo $cart[$i]->id; ?> </td>   
         <td><?php echo $cart[$i]->game; ?> </td>   
         <td><?php echo $cart[$i]->price; ?> </td>   
         <td><?php echo $cart[$i]->stsdium; ?> </td>
         <td><?php echo $cart[$i]->quantity; ?> </td>
         <td><?php echo $cart[$i]->price * $cart[$i]->quantity; ?> </td>   
     </tr>    

    <?php } ?>

</table>       
          <a href=" buytickets.php">Add more tickets to your cart</a>      
          </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid there are quite a lot of problems here.

- First, two obvious ones: you have `$relult` instead of `$result` on
  line 5. You have `$i-0` instead of `$i=0` on line 29.
- Furthermore, you're performing a query (a non-safe one, have a look
  at [parameter binding](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) with PDO) using `$_GET['id']`, while you don't
  appear to be sure this variable will be available: you check on line
  8 if it is set, but that check is performed after injecting that
  unknown value in a query...
- On line 14 you are presuming that `$_SESSION['cart']` is an array, although this array has not been defined before.
- What's up with `$cart = unserialize(serialize($_SESSION['cart']))`? If the cart is an array of `Item` objects, you can simply iterate like so:
  `foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $item) { echo $item->id; /*etc*/ }`

Answer (score 0):

> Undefined index id

I guess `$_GET['id']` is undefined. Maybe you need `$_POST['id']` or `$_SESSION['id']`?
See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3477374/5516047) to see the difference between GET and POST.

> undefined variable result

You got a typo in line 5. `$relult =` should be `$result =`.

> undefined variable i

Again a typo, this time in line 28: `for($i-0;` should be `for($i=0;`.

Your first access at `$_SESSION['cart']` should be a check if it's set and an array. Do something like this to initialize the value:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['cart']) || !is_array($_SESSION['cart'])  
    $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
```

The line

```
<td colspan="11"><h4> Upcoming games 2016/2017</h3> <td>
```

should be covered in a `<tr>` element and the typo `<h4></h3>` needs to be fixed. Why is the colspan 11 when you only got 6 columns?

```
$cart = unserialize(serialize($_SESSION['cart']));
```

This doesn't make sense to me. Why not `$cart = $_SESSION['cart'];`?
Beware that you didn't set `$cart[$i]->stsdium;`. Did you mean stadium?

Also you should think about [filtering](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) GET and POST values and use [prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to increase security.
Filtering the id from POST could look like this:

```
$id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'id', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
```